# Showing the values when form loaded

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

Hi all i have main form with a treeview control with a set of files displayed under each node. If i had my mouse over that node i will read the values that are present in the text file by using the following code

```
 private void treeViewACH_NodeMouseHover(object sender, TreeNodeMouseHoverEventArgs e)
    {
        string strFile = string.Empty;
        System.Text.StringBuilder messageBoxCS = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        messageBoxCS.AppendFormat(" {0}", e.Node);
        strFile = messageBoxCS.ToString().Substring(11);
        strFilePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        strFilePath = Directory.GetParent(strFilePath).ToString();
        strFilePath = Directory.GetParent(strFilePath).ToString();
        strFilePath = strFilePath + "\\ACH" + "\\" + strFile;


        if ((File.Exists(strFilePath)))
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strFilePath);
            StringComparison compareType = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strFilePath);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(strFilePath);
            if (fileName.StartsWith("FileHeader", compareType)
                && extension.Equals(".txt", compareType))
            {
                string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                //sb.Append("RecordTypeCode\tPriorityCode");
                //sb.Append("\n");
                //sb.Append("--------------------------------------------------");
                //sb.Append("\n");
                objFile.ReferenceTypeCode = s.Substring(0, 1);
                sb.Append(objFile.ReferenceTypeCode);
                string PriorCode = s.Substring(1, 2);
                sb.Append(PriorCode);
                objFile.getValues(sb.ToString());
                frmTemp frmtemp = new frmTemp();
                frmtemp.Show();

            }
        }
```

Now i would like to place the values in each textboxes on the form load.  But as it is a different form i can not access the values from the business layer

I have coded like this on form load

```
         BL.FileHeader objFile = new FileHeader();
         private void frmTemp_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = objFile.ReferenceTypeCode;
    }
```

But i am unable to display the values any help please..

Comment: Any one please help me. I got strucked at this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer by the following

```
           frmTemp frmtmp = new frmTemp(strFileHeader);
            frmtmp.Show();

      public frmTemp(string str)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (str.StartsWith("1"))
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = str.Substring(0, 1);
        }
        else if (str.StartsWith("5"))
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = str.Substring(0, 1);
            this.textBox2.Text = str.Substring(4, 16);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a property to your `frmTemp` class for each value that you want to display. In your `NodeMouseHover` handler, assign values to those properties right after you create the instance of the form. Then, in the `frmTemp_Load` handler, assign the values of those properties to the `TextBox` controls.